# How to send parameters inside Vue's v-for to a function?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How to pass as a parameter `{{ item.id }}` to my function `productos.mostrarModal()` in a `v-for` loop in vue.js?

```
<div v-for="item of articulos">
    <a href="#" onclick="productos.mostrarModal()"  >
        <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
        <i><h5>{{item.marca}}</h5></i>
        <img :src="item.picture" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Which other tag could I use instead or with the div? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

replace `onclick` by `@click` event and pass the parameter to its handler like `productos.mostrarModal(item.id)` :

```
<div v-for="item of articulos">
    <a href="#" @click="productos.mostrarModal(item.id)"  >
        <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
        <i><h5>{{item.marca}}</h5></i>
        <img :src="item.picture" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Vue eventHandler: `v-bind:click="handler"`, or the short version `@click="handler"`. There are bindings for all events as far as I know.

For completeness: a `v-for` loop requires a unique `key` attribute, which can be the `index` for example.

And if you want to acces the `event`, as well as custom parameters in your `eventHandler`, you can pass the `$event` parameter as first argument.

e.g.:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) of articulos" :key="index">
    <a href="#" @click="productos.mostrarModal($event, item.id)"  >
        <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
        <i><h5>{{item.marca}}</h5></i>
        <img :src="item.picture" />
    </a>
</div>
```